# How to show/hide comments in XCode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, comments, shortcut

While programming in XCode 8.2.1, I am simply trying to perform the following action:

[image: This is what XCode says to do]

... but when I try to do this (either by using the mouse/menu, or using the shortcut: "Control-Shift-Command-Left Arrow") , I get the unexpected result of the "Funk" alert sound... and no folding/unfolding takes place.

I have researched the question but all other posts are outdated.

Is this a known bug or am I just doing something wrong?

Thankyou!!!!

Comment: It is working for me. It works only in multi line comments like /*...*/  and /**...*/

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried putting comments in like that to test it but it still has this behavior... strange.

Comment: It worked for me in Objective-C and not working in Swift.